# Не прогружаются стили на странице

Tags: ip, vpn

Вопрос может не по теме стака, но все же может кто-то сможет помочь. Периодически(через день-2) при загрузке некоторых страниц, стили страниц не грузятся, то бишь грузится просто html код без css. Долго не мог понять почему это происходит и лечится само по себе, но тут заметил, что если я включаю vpn или прокси, то проблема пропадает. Т.е сайт как-то периодически блочит мой ip? Тогда почему он вообще грузится хоть как-то

Answer (score 1):

"если я включаю vpn или прокси, то проблема пропадает". Я думаю очевидно, что стили загружаются на сайт с определенного cdn, то есть вы загружаете стили по ссылке, и сайт с которого вы загружаете стили блокируется провайдером, поэтому с vpn проблем нет.